# How to get app version using AngularJs and ionic 2?

Tags: angularjs, ionic2, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to show app version using old AngularJs version 1.5.3 and Ionic version 2.2.1. how to show the app version?

Example:

````
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="30400" android:versionName="3.4.0" package="com.Range.Range_Android" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

etc tags

</manifest>```

Here I want to refer android:versionName="3.4.0" from AndroidManifest.xml file. I want refer only for version number. Please Help.
````

Comment: By "app version" you mean the last published version in your version control?

Comment: @aUXcoder yes, Are you having any solution?

Comment: @aUXcoder The version is available in AndroidManifest.xml. How I want to refer that file and show on the useragreement page. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

### Cordova

1. Download the following

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-app-version 
npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/app-version
```

2. Get the version as follow

```js
import { AppVersion } from '@ionic-native/app-version/ngx'

export class FooBarComponent {
 constructor(private _appVersion: AppVersion) {
   this._appVersion
        .getVersionNumber()
        .then((version) => {
         console.log(version)
        })
        .catch(() => {
          console.warn('cannot get the version')
        }
 }
}
```

### Capacitor

Actually not doable -> [How to get the package.log version with angular, ionic & capacitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72867371/how-to-get-the-package-log-version-with-angular-ionic-capacitor)