# How to get the package.log version with angular, ionic & capacitor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, package.json, capacitor

I used the following pugin: [cordova-plugin-app-version](https://github.com/sampart/cordova-plugin-app-version), to get the version of my app and displayed it into my html file.

But I did the migration to Capacitor and cannot find the way to do that with it.

Does somebody find a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily import it in your .ts file.

```
import p from '[path to your file]/package.json';
```

Then you have access to all the properties in your package.json:

```
version = p.version;
```

Then you can display it in your HTML:

```
<div>{{version}}</div>
```

Comment: Seems like this'll do the trick, did you tested it in production ?

Comment: Yes, it will work in production. There is no reason why it shouldn't :)